# Error in query when writing insert into statement

Tags: sql

I need to create a table in SQL and insert values,my code for it is

```
CREATE TABLE CASE_DETAILS
(
    id int,
    queuename char(50),
    entrydate int
);

INSERT INTO CASE_DETAILS (id, queuename, entrydate)
VALUES (1002, 'Maker', 1/10/2020),
       (1003, 'Checker', 2/10/2020),
       (1004, 'Exception', 17/11/2020),
       (1005, 'Exception', 15/11/2020);
```

I am getting error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Please help

Comment: which dbms are you using ? and also you are trying to put a date format into an int ,that's the issue

Comment: Have you tried entering dates as '2020-01-19' (including quotation marks)?

Comment: yes, i have tried still getting errors

Comment: Your column **entrydate** is defined as `INT`, but looks as if it should really be `DATE` .....

Answer (score 0):

Revised per feedback:

Using SQL Server, your date formats are probably off.  You are submitting DD/MM/YYYY, but the database is likely configured by default for MM/DD/YYYY.  You can either fix the default date format of the database, or adjust your query as such...

```
CREATE TABLE CASE_DETAILS
(
  id int,
  queuename char(50),
  entrydate DATETIME
);

insert into CASE_DETAILS (id, queuename, entrydate)
VALUES
(1002, 'Maker', '10/01/2020'),
(1003, 'Checker', '10/02/2020'),
(1004, 'Exception', '11/17/2020'),
(1005, 'Exception', '11/15/2020');
```

OR (universal format per @DRapp)

```
CREATE TABLE CASE_DETAILS
(
  id int,
  queuename char(50),
  entrydate DATETIME
);

insert into CASE_DETAILS (id, queuename, entrydate)
VALUES
(1002, 'Maker', '2020-10-01'),
(1003, 'Checker', '2020-10-02'),
(1004, 'Exception', '2020-11-17'),
(1005, 'Exception', '2020-11-15');
```

Please see dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=18b47161f1c1eab25edbbe4fbae76bc6)

[image]

Comment: What specific database are you using?  What do you mean when you say "its not working"?

Comment: I am using sql server

Comment: You probably need to do universal date/time for insert such as '2020-01-10'  (yyyy-mm-dd) as it is probably choking on dates

Comment: @ArchitaMukherjee Per Stack Overflow procedures, please mark this question as answered so that others may benefit from it as well.